How to read a resource file from disk using Delphi?
How to read a .res file from disk? Not attached to an .exe, so I can easily update the .res file without needing the .exe?
Something like this:
function LoadResourceFromDisk(const FileName, ResName: string): TStream;
var
  ResourceStream: TResourceStream;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := nil;
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    ResourceStream := TResourceStream.CreateFromStream(FileStream, ResName);
    try
      Result := ResourceStream;
    finally
      ResourceStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;

but function CreateFromStream() doesn't exist.

Take a look at this unit: https://delphidabbler.com/software/resfile. Maybe it helps you.

According to Resource File Formats documentation the data stored in *.res file is not stored in same format as when it is compiled into executable. So you won't be able to access such resources in the same way. Usually when you wish to have resource independent from your application executable you compile such resources into a Resource-only DLL. Another common way of working with external resources is to use Virtual File System to store multiple resources in a single file.

Why not just maintain a textual .rc file with the needed data, and then compile that into a .res file when needed?

Thanks @Leonard, with your answer i was able to do what i need.

Try with the following helper method:
function LoadResourceFromDisk(const FileName, ResName: string): TMemoryStream;
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  ResHeader: TResHeader;
  ResData: TBytes;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    while FileStream.Position < FileStream.Size do
    begin
      // Read resource header
      FileStream.ReadBuffer(ResHeader, SizeOf(ResHeader));
      // Check if this is the resource we're looking for
      if ResHeader.ResName = ResName then
      begin
        // Read resource data
        SetLength(ResData, ResHeader.DataSize);
        FileStream.ReadBuffer(ResData[0], ResHeader.DataSize);
        // Write to result stream
        Result.WriteBuffer(ResData[0], ResHeader.DataSize);
        Break;
      end
      else
        // Skip to next resource
        FileStream.Position := FileStream.Position + ResHeader.DataSize;
    end;
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;


This leaks if there's an exception. Also, it is very wasteful to read the entire data block into a temp buffer just to copy it to a memory stream.

You can use TStream.CopyFrom() to read from one stream into another. And you can use TStream.Seek() instead of Position := Position + Size.
